# Using regex to break string into a dictionary with key and values

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to turn this list into a list full of dictionaries. Below I included a snippet of the full list Im using.

With row 4.1 as an example, I want:

- the key to be the row number, ('4.1')
- the values to include the title ('Properties occupied by  the company
  (less $  43,332,898 \nencumbrances')
- and the four numbers after it as a list ['68,122,291',  '0',
  '68,122,291', '64,237,046'].

I got the general loop for how I'd put together each separate dictionary. Where I am struggling is coming up with regex patterns to get the row title and row values. Its difficult since some of the row titles also include numbers. Another issue is that not all of the rows have four numbers at the end. For these instances, I just want the available numbers.  Any help figure out the regex to grab these would be appreciated.

```
    clean = ['4.1 Properties occupied by  the company (less $  43,332,898 \nencumbrances)  68,122,291  0  68,122,291  64,237,046 \n',
         '4.2 Properties held for  the production of income (less \n $    encumbrances)  0  0   0  0 \n',
         '4.3 Properties held for sale (less $  \nencumbrances)      0  0 \n',]
    
    clean_list = []
    
    for n in clean:
        row_num = re.findall(r'\d+\.',n)
        row_title = 
        row_values = 
        new_dict = {row_num: row_title, row_values}
        clean_list.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: Why a list of dictionaries, and not one dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want a separate dictionary for each line, each with just one key. I would think it more useful to end up with one dictionary with several keys.

```
d = {}
for line in clean:
    parts = re.match(r"^([\d.]+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d[\d,.]*)\s*(?:(\d[\d,.]*)\s*)?(?:(\d[\d,.]*)\s*)?(?:(\d[\d,.]*)\s*)?$",
            line, re.DOTALL)
    code, title, *values = parts.group(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    d[code] = (title, list(filter(None, values)))
```

For the sample data, the value of `d` would be:

```
{
  '4.1': (
    'Properties occupied by  the company (less $  43,332,898 \nencumbrances)', 
    ['68,122,291', '0', '68,122,291', '64,237,046']
  ), 
  '4.2': (
    'Properties held for  the production of income (less \n $    encumbrances)',
    ['0', '0', '0', '0']
  ), 
  '4.3': (
    'Properties held for sale (less $  \nencumbrances)', 
    ['0', '0']
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Also you were right its better for me to have one dictionary with several keys.

Answer (score 0):

Following the examples shared by you

- "4.1 Properties occupied by  the company (less $  43,332,898 \nencumbrances)  68,122,291  0  68,122,291  64,237,046"
- "4.2 Properties held for  the production of income (less \n $    encumbrances)  0  0   0  0"
- "4.3 Properties held for sale (less $  \nencumbrances)      0  0 "

```
for n in clean:
    row_num = re.search(r'$\d+\.\d+',n).group()
    row_title = re.search(r'(?<=\d+\.\d+).*?(?=((\d+,?)+ ?)+$)', n}.group()
    row_values = re.search(r'((\d+,?)+ ?)+$', n).group()
    new_dict = {row_num: row_title, row_values}
        clean_list.append(new_dict)
```

I would seriously recommend going through https://regexr.com/ and trying these patterns and messing with them to learn. The solution is not important. It's how you end up at it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split()` to accommodate variable number of the last values into a list.  if your data always has the parenthesis you can use those as part of the pattern:

```py
for n in clean:
    row_num, row_title, row_values = re.findall(
        r'^(\d+\.\d+)\s+(.*\))\s+(.*)$', n, re.DOTALL)[0]
    new_dict = {row_num: (row_title, row_values.split())}
    clean_list.append(new_dict)
```

keeping your use of `re.findall()`.  output looks like:

```py
[{'4.1': ('Properties occupied by  the company (less $  43,332,898 \n'
          'encumbrances)',
          ['68,122,291', '0', '68,122,291', '64,237,046'])},
 {'4.2': ('Properties held for  the production of income (less \n'
          ' $    encumbrances)',
          ['0', '0', '0', '0'])},
 {'4.3': ('Properties held for sale (less $  \nencumbrances)', ['0', '0'])}]
```

this retains the newlines, if you want those.